# is there a way to disable storing speech items in the wit.ai inbox?

Tags: speech-recognition, wit.ai

By default, all speech items sent to wit.ai for speech recognition and stored on inbox. I would like to disable storing them by default or to control when they can be stored. If not, all users commands are stored there which I think it could be not always a good practice.

TIA